# Pensions - Where to start? (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, pension, retirement-plan

**What are the key decisions that I need to make and what key information should I know before starting a Pension in the UK?**

I am 24 and living in the UK. I want, well more like should, start a pension relatively soon. However I keep getting told it's an important decision and there are scare stories regarding people's pension funds which I don't entirely understand but has concerned me anyway.

So I wondered where I could find out what are the key areas I should know about before deciding which type, and which provide, to go with? O

ne question I wondered about was how to actually pay per month, can you get it to come out of your paycheck automatically as a %?

Thank You

Comment: What pension does you employer offer?  These are often the best option depending on the small print!  You can specify a percentage of your salary to be paid into it every month, at least all the employers I've had have done this.

Answer (score 5):

Pensions in the UK are a real free-for-all. A few years ago, the government introduced *stakeholder* pensions to try and simplify things, but if anything it's just made things more complex.

To give you an idea, everyone has access to a *Basic state retirement pension*, but there's also *SERPS* (state earnings related pension scheme) and the *State second pension* provided by the government. Then in the private sector there are the aforementioned *Stakeholder pensions*, *Self Invested Personal Pensions*, *Final salary occupational pension* schemes and *Money purchase occupational pension* schemes.

For a good summary, take a look at [this excellent *Times* article](http://www.timesonline.co.uk/tol/money/pensions/article575558.ece) and for more details, have a look at the [*Pensions in the United Kingdom* Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pensions_in_the_United_Kingdom) or browse around the Which? [retirement section](http://www.which.co.uk/money/retirement/) or the moneysavingsexpert [pensions pages](http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/savings/discount-pensions).

The main things to look out for are whether your company offers a *defined benefits scheme*, or a money purchase scheme where they offer pay additional contributions or offer to match your additional contributions. Either of these are likely to be better than just buying a money purchase scheme pension privately.

Comment: +1 for the MoneySavingExport link - the introduction alone is worth a read: http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/savings/discount-pensions

Comment: Some of this information is now a bit out of date, the MoneySavingExpert link is still good though

Comment: Thanks @RobinGBrown, I don't have the time to research this now, but if you suggest some improvements I'd be happy to review and accept them. Alternatively, write a good answer of your own and I'd be happy to vote it up.